# How to clear cache in Pentaho

Tags: caching, jndi, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I am using Pentaho 5. My dimensions keep changing frequently and I need the changes to be applied to the dashboard, this is not possible because Pentaho keeps caching. I have created the cube using the datasource wizard and the querys using mdx over mondrian jndi. Even though I set the property Cache to false or set cache duration doesn't seem to work. Is there a API that I can use with mondrian jndi to clear cache? Or are there any property files that I should change? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In **Pentahoo 7** the "Clear Cache" option is in a different Menu:

**Tools** -> **Database** -> **Clear Cache**

If you are using Database lookup and if you are getting older fields, cleaning cache can actually solved the problem.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually inside Pentaho User Console: Tools -> Refresh -> Mondrian Schema Cache.

Or you can make schedule for refreshing cache: find **clear_mondrian_schema_cache.xaction** inside your installation and schedule it.

Comment: The scheduler in Pentaho doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to run the xaction file using windows task scheduler?

Comment: How it doesn't seem to work? What did you do, and what happened?

Comment: It does not allow to create a new task. The create new task button is disabled. It does not allow to edit the default tasks as well. Am I missing a plugin?

Comment: :-) Choose 'Browse Files' after login page. Navigate to file, select it, end on the right will appear 'Schedule..'

Comment: and* - writing mistake

Comment: Is this available in the open source version of Pentaho 5?

Comment: The `clear_mondrian_schema_cache.xaction` file is not available in the Pentaho 5 CE. You can call `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/system/refresh/mondrianSchemaCache` instead. And potentially create ETL job or transformation and schedule it on Pentaho server.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You can read http://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform500/webservice500/ for api details.

 And also you can refresh Reporting Metadata Cache via web service, you can use the following web service call:
    http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/system/refresh/metadata

**Option2:**   You can navigate to *\biserver-ee\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\classes*
and change the configuration file "ehcache.xml"

```
<cache name="report-dataset-cache"
maxElementsInMemory="50"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="1"
timeToLiveSeconds="2"
diskPersistent="false"
diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1"
/>
```

If you have done that and still no positive answer, I think you have not restarted the BA server. If the issue still exists comment below.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1. One is to schedule "clear mondrian schema"  on ba server but for that to happen , you need to get clear_mondrian_schema.xml from pentaho-solutions/systems folder and upload it in some folder that you can access on ba server. You can then use normal schedule file options to achieve you want. This put a lof of load on BA server though.
2. My second recommendation is if you are using cubes/schema and building using schema workbench, you can turn the caching off. If your database is architecturally good and your schemas all well defined, user will get updates/new data as soon as they refresh.